# Define Functions out of Class template in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I've been faced to an Error  class Stack' used without template parameters" > while I trying to make a **template Stack class**

```
template <class T>
class Stack{                        /// Declare A NEW Class NAMED STACK

private :
    T* data;
    int pointer;
    int size1;

public :
    T pop();
    T top();
    bool push(T);
    bool isfull();
    bool isempty();
    Stack(int size1)
    {
        this->size1 = size1;
        pointer = 0;
        data = new int [size1];
    }
    ~Stack()
    {
        delete [] data;
    }

};
```

The Real Problem is that I want To Define Functions Outside of the template class!!(For More Readability) But It Doesnt Work!!

Here's My Defenition for one of functions :

```
template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::isfull()
{
if(pointer==size1+1)
    return true;

return false;
}
```

If This function's definition Steps into class code block , It works fine But ...?!

This is How i call it in main :
    Stack Operator(size) ;

Comment: I don't see anything here that would cause this error. Show us how you are instantiating an object of the class in main.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Just curious -- when you have `data = new int [size1];` isn't you are determining `data` to be of `int *` rather than the way you defined it `T* data`?  This should not give any errors, but just curious.

Comment: Are you defining the functions in a `.cpp` file?  Template functions generally need to be defined in the header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you missed out a `<T>` from one of your function definitions?  I.e. have this:

```
template <class T>
bool Stack::isempty()
```

instead of this:

```
template <class T>
bool Stack<T>::isempty()
          ^^^
```

Comment: Thanks !!! 
You Helped Much!!!I didn't save the header after i changed it,so the compliler give that ridiculous Error !!
Thanks Again!!

Answer (score 0):

After many years' c++ programming, I realized that:

> **If you don't how to use template in c++ you just know half of C++.**

Long story short, there are two ways to define a template class:

A. Get rid of cpp file, Put all functions' body inside the class h file

B. Put the functions' body in cpp file, but don't add this file in the project. And at the very end of the h file add a include line like this:

```
#include "xxxx.cpp"
```

you don't have to call it cpp, you can call it whatever you want

Comment: erm, aren't you getting it the other way? The `.h` file should be included in the `.cpp` file. And not the other way around.

Comment: Include cpp file in h file is the key point, I am using iPhone typing this, cann't have too many words to explain why

Comment: A better method would be to use a different extension - `.inc` is commonly used for this.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us this detail, but you may simply be making the mistake of trying to implement the function in a cpp file instead of a header file.

Template functions need to be implemented in header files.